# How to compare 2 lists of objects and remove the items that are not common?

Tags: c#

I've got 2 generic lists that do not contain the all fields of the same type

```
IList<Category> and List<CategoriesRow>Categories

categoryList = IList<Category>
```

but both have common fields Name and ID.

I want to compare list Categories with categoryList and find those from categoryList where categoryList[index].ID does not exist in the list of all Categories of ID. For all those that do not exist in Categories, I will have to remove them from CatgoryList.

I had a previous post in which I was given examples of LINQ, but the problem is I have to use Dynamic, implying that I am passing categoryList and Categories as Dynamic.

Can anyone give me an example how to go about the above as I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Edit your code fragment to make it readable plz.

Comment: Why do you have to use dynamic?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `.Except` LINQ operator.

Like this:

```
var uniqueList = list1.Except(list2);
```

Not sure what you mean by "I have to use Dynamic".

This is a standard LINQ operation available to all types that implement `IEnumerable`.

[Here's](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/ExceptOperator.ashx) a good article on doing it.

Comment: As I understand the question the lists are not of the same type, so Except can't be used here.

Comment: Sorry, didnt see that (answered before his code was cleaned up). You're right.

Answer (score 1):

let say you have a `list1` and `list2` like this:

```
IList<Category> list1 = new List<Category>();
IList<CategoryRow> list2 = new List<CategoryRow>();
//populate lists here....
```

Now to select from `list1` only those items that have a matching `Id` in `list2`, you could do

```
list1 = list1.Where(c => list2.Exists(cr => cr.Id == c.Id)).ToList();
```

Hope that answers your question

Comment: that's way bigO :) i would suggest using some kind of index (eg. dictionary) to search in your `c => list2.Exists()`)

Comment: yeah, your probably right... but the specs dont say anything about it being fast ;) Anyway, i feel writing alot of unasked-for code would detract from the solution and clutter the answer