# How to compare 2 lists of objects and remove the items that are not common?

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.0

I've got 2 generic lists that do not contain the all fields of the same type

```
IList<Category> and List<CategoriesRow>Categories

categoryList = IList<Category>
```

but both have common fields Name and ID.

I want to compare list Categories with categoryList and find from categoryList where categoryList[index].ID does not exist in the list of all Categories of ID. For all those that do not exist in Categories, I will have to remove them from CatgoryList.

I had [a previous post in which I was given examples of LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243631/how-to-compare-2-lists-of-objects-and-remove-the-items-that-are-not-common), but the problem is I have to use Dynamic, implying that I am passing categoryList and Categories as Dynamic.

Can anyone give me an example how to go about the above as I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare 2 lists of objects and remove the items that are not common?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243631/how-to-compare-2-lists-of-objects-and-remove-the-items-that-are-not-common)

Comment: why do you *have to use dynamic*? Why not prefer type safety over typeless classes? Is this a textbook question perhaps? ( @Jon: that's the q. the user281180 is referring to himself ;)

Comment: ya, I think my question was posted twice!

Answer (score 0):

First run a loop of all list element of `CategoryList`
Run the inner loop of all list element of `Categories`
Compare the id of CategoryList[index].ID with Categories[InnerIndex].ID
When the inner loop is finish, check if the condition is ever true in whole loop if so then the ID is exists in Categories otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = categoryList.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  int id = categoryList[i].ID;
  if (!Categories.Any(r => r.ID == id)) categoryList.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: I am using dynamic, hence can`t use LINQ or lambda

Comment: Why not? I can use such code even if either `CategoriesRow` or `Category` is dynamic. Are you using some beta version of .NET4? Do you get an exception? If so, post it.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
for (int i = 0; i < CategoryList.Count; i++) { 
        if (!CategoryList.Contains(Categories[i]))
            Categories.RemoveAt(i);
        if (!Categories.Contains(CategoryList[i]))
            CategoryList.RemoveAt(i);
    }
```

Comment: I am having the error message Error 4 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'API.Category to 'MvcUI.Models.CategoryRow' \MvcUI\Models\ProjectModel.cs 330 55 MvcUI

Category is a class and CatregoryRow is another class, which i`m using for the list<object>

Comment: 4 Life: That can't work since the two lists are not of the same type. @user281180: my answer does *exactly* what you asked for (removes objects that have no `ID` in `Categories` from `categoryList`).

Comment: @Jaroslav thanks for answering.  I am using dynamic and due to that I can`t use lambda, hence can`t apply it! I can`t use LINQ in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id;
}

public class CategoriesRow
{
    public int Id;
}

public List<Category> RemoveNotUsedCategories(List<Category> categoryList, List<CategoriesRow> Categories)
{
    List<Category> usedCategories = new List<Category>();

    foreach (Category usableCat in categoryList)
    {
        foreach (CategoriesRow catRow in Categories)
        {
            if (usableCat.Id == catRow.Id)
            {
                // Add categories that are used.
                usedCategories.Add(usableCat);
                // Will break the first loop.
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return usedCategories;
}
```